# How to install a DebugBreak handler?

Tags: c++, windows, assert, debugbreak

We are setting up Appveyor for our Visual Studio solution, which produces a C++ library. A few of our tests [dumb] fuzz C++ objects to ensure they don't do something unexpected. Under debug builds it causes an assert to fire (and in release builds it just throws).

We use a custom assert to avoid Posix behavior of crashing a program being debugged. It is shown below. It appears Appveyor or the Operating System kills the program if an assert fires and a debugger is not attached:

[image]

We want to install a `DebugBreak` handler if a debugger is not present. This should confirm its the OS doing the killing. Ideally, the handler will work from Windows XP onwards and VS2002 and above (those are the Windows combinations we support).

How do we install a `DebugBreak` handler on Windows platforms?

---

```
#  define MYLIB_ASSERT(exp) {                                     \
    if (!(exp)) {                                                 \
      std::ostringstream oss;                                     \
      oss << "Assertion failed: " << (char*)(__FILE__) << "("     \
          << (int)(__LINE__) << "): " << (char*)(__FUNCTION__)    \
          << std::endl;                                           \
      std::cerr << oss.str();                                     \
      __debugbreak();                                             \
    }                                                             \
}
```

---

We can't really tell who is responsible at the because the behavior is not documented on MSDN at [DebugBreak and __debugbreak](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ea9yy3ey.aspx) or [C/C++ Assertions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ww5t02fa.aspx).

Comment: `DebugBreak handler` - exist general exception handler, which you and must install. no special `DebugBreak handler`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few distinct ways to handle this.

From the process that launches the one that may call `DebugBreak()`, you can use [`WaitForDebugEvent`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681423.aspx) (or `WaitForDebugEventEx`) and [`ContinueDebugEvent`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679285.aspx) to handle debug events from the child. I.e., the parent acts as a debugger, and the child as a debuggee, similar to how Visual Studio (among many others) debugger works.

You can also attach to a running process using [`DebugActiveProcess`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679295.aspx). After you've attached, most of debugging is similar to a parent debugging its child process.

If you can't (or don't want to) do either of those, you can install a post-mortem debugger. You do this by specifying the debugger in the registry, as described [on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff542967.aspx). Windows has a "Windows Error Reporting" (WER), which invokes the specified post-mortem debugger.

Comment: Thanks Jerry. Its going to take a few days for me to try it and fully test it. I'll knock the dust off of John Robbin's debugging book...

Comment: I *think* the [parent debugger can usually detach](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679301(v=vs.85).aspx) by calling DebugActiveProcessStop.  But I'm not sure what caveats there may be.

Comment: debugger can detach. this is 100%

Comment: @RbMm: Yup--serves me right for depending on memory, I guess.

Answer (score 1):

> We want to install a DebugBreak handler if a debugger is not present.

you need install usual windows exception handler, by using [*__try / __except*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/swezty51.aspx) or by [`AddVectoredExceptionHandler`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679274(v=vs.85).aspx) or by [`SetUnhandledExceptionFilter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680634(v=vs.85).aspx)

when `int 3` instruction is executed in your app (by calling [`__debugbreak`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f408b4et.aspx) or [`DebugBreak`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679297(v=vs.85).aspx)) - and debugger not present or not handle this - your exception handler will be called with exception code `STATUS_BREAKPOINT`.